# Respect both location directives in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver

The following makes nginx not to pass to the PHP-FPM fastcgi server because I created a location block:

```
location = /test.php {
    auth_basic "Nope.";
    auth_basic_user_file /test.htpasswd;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    include params/fastcgi;

    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:4623;
}
```

Means: if the first location block matches, it seems that the second one is ignored. Is there any *solution* for this without copying the fastcgi-stuff from the second location block into the first one?

Comment: Would you mind to show example request where the problem is present?
The first will match http://domain/test.php.

The rest of the php should be handled by the other location. I would like to see how are u testing this conf.

Comment: I test it by calling test.php and seeing that the php code appears in my browser ;-) All other php files work.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put all your fastcgi configuration on a file and include it on both locations.

Things like nested locations may prone your configuration buggy and more difficult to understand and maintain.

Comment: Is this the correct solution? Is there no way to say 'hey, please look at other location blocks too?

Comment: Check the following link: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html . Thee you will find that "...nginx first searches for the most specific prefix location given by literal strings regardless of the listed order...". You are using the "/test.php" literal and nginx wont match any other location.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be best practice to do so.